# Why does the GIT is uploading the empty folder when it's full of code?

Tags: git, github

I created a repository in Github and was trying to upload some Python code there. One of the sub-folder is uploaded empty which I don't reason out. I created new repository with different name and still facing the same issue. Later, I remove the `origin` using `git remote rm origin` and dont see any effect for that.  Here is the picture for the upload,

[image]

The folder name with some code is `ML Examples` and it uploaded as empty. I was tried to change the name to `ML` earlier and deleted later on. However, it still shows in the upload.

What's the issue here and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see (gray folder) is a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) of your main GitHub repo which records the nested repo root SHA1.

If you want to reference its content as well, you should add those nested repos as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Or you should avoid for those subdirectories to have a `.git/` folder in them, as that would make them nested git repo.

Comment: One question, why does all the sub-folder is uploaded but the ML Examples ? I need good explanation on that.

Comment: Because MK Example includes a .git folder in it, making it a nested git repo. In that case, your main repo only records a gitlink, which is what you see on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU `git` don't really care about directories, only about files inside them.

That is, you need to `git add somedir/somefile`

<sup>(but I am a newbie on git and could be wrong)</sup>

Comment: You are correct: Git does not record empty directories, in that it does not really record directories at all, except by implication (i.e, a file named `a/b/c` implies that directories `a` and `a/b` must exist). In this case, however, VonC is right (as always :-) ): what the questioner created is a "gitlink" entry, which is essentially a file containing a commit hash ID for a submodule. GitHub displays these specially because Git checks out the submodule (provided you have set up the *rest* of the requirements for submodules).